# Integer values of a rational function

Tags: roots

How does one analytically determine the integer values of a rational function $f(x)$$=$$\frac{40-8x}{8x+2}mod1$ where $x$ is an element of the rationals?  I just gave the function listed as an example, I would like to know the generally preferred methods (if they exist) of analytically determining integer values of rational functions.

Comment: Did you really mean $\mod{1}$?

Comment: @EthanHunt Yes, as $f(x)$ doesn't take on only integer values for rational (or even integer) $x$.

Comment: This is not "modular-forms", nor "modular-arithmetic".  As I understand it, you simply want to find when $(40-8x)/(8x+2)$ is an integer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael edited tags to reflect.  How does one obtain the integer solutions though analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation $\frac{40 - 8 x}{8 x + 2} = y$ by the denominator and you have a linear equation in $x$: solve to get

$$ x = \dfrac{20-y}{4+4y} $$
Note that if $y$ is an integer (other than $-1$), $x$ is a rational number.